# Android Honeycomb GridView Widgets

Tags: android, gridview, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

Can anyone give me an example where I can understand how to use GridView on RemoveViews for Honeycomb?

I see only StackWidgets into Android Developers examples.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Android source code. Browser code has bookmark widget source + resources.
Atleast ICS code has it. U can look in for Honeycomb.